Select tables that don't have any records in a Firebird 4.0 database
I have a Firebird 4.0 DB that has 724 tables and I need search for some data. First, I would like to drop the tables that don't have any records. Is there something in Firebird like the example in MySQL below?
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database MySQL>;

A query that returns the tables that don't have any records or the table with the number of rows, etc.. something that help me to identify which tables are empty.
I tried some queries using $rdb$relations but nothing worked.

It would be faster if you just ask database owner where you can find needed information. Firebird has no queries like this.

You can use the commandline tool gstat, e.g. gstat -u <your user> -d -r <database>, which will report several statistics for all tables, including the number of rows.
Otherwise, you will need to write a stored procedure or execute block for this yourself (which can be slow to run for large databases), for example:
execute block returns (TABLE_NAME varchar(63) character set UTF8, TABLE_ROWS bigint)
as
begin
  for select trim(RDB$RELATION_NAME) from RDB$RELATIONS
      where RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0 and RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0
      into TABLE_NAME do
  begin
    execute statement 'select count(*) from "' || replace(TABLE_NAME, '"', '""') || '"' 
        into TABLE_ROWS;
    suspend;
  end
end

This does assume that you have the select privilege on all tables. You may need to login as SYSDBA, or as a user with the RDB$ADMIN role to be able to query all tables.
If you only want to output rows with TABLE_ROWS = 0, you'll need to make the suspend statement conditional, e.g.:
if (TABLE_ROWS = 0) then suspend;

As mrapi pointed out in the comments, if you're really only interested if a table has no rows, you can also check if there is no row at all or at least one row:
execute block returns (TABLE_NAME varchar(63) character set UTF8)
as
declare variable EMPTY boolean;
begin
  for select trim(RDB$RELATION_NAME) from RDB$RELATIONS
      where RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0 and RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0
      order by RDB$RELATION_NAME
      into TABLE_NAME do
  begin
    EMPTY = true;
    execute statement 'select false from "' || replace(TABLE_NAME, '"', '""') 
        || '" fetch first row only' 
        into EMPTY;
    if (EMPTY) then suspend;
  end
end

This exploits the fact that the variable is not updated if there is no row at all, so it still has the true value assigned before the execute statement (other variants are possible, e.g. using select exists(...) from RDB$DATABASE).

if the result is only for empty tables,'select count(*) ' can be replaced with 'select first 1 1 from.. '
